# print awk array and replace special characters with comma

Tags: awk, command-line, printf

I hope the title explains this correctly. I am currently trying to print out an array after counting unique values from a spreadsheet.

My awk command works correctly:

```
awk -F"," 'NR>1{col[$1,$9]++} END {for (i in col) printf("%s: %d\n", i, col[i])}' my_file.csv | sort
```

When printing though I get a special character that looks like a question mark.

[image: output]

How do I print this with a comma + space between the year and the season.

eg: 1896, summer: 151

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Awk is treating `[$1,$9]` as a pseudo multi-dimensional array, and inserting its internal `SUBSEP` character. This is documented in [The GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#User_002dmodified) for example:

> SUBSEP
>
> The subscript separator. It has the default value of "\034" and is used to separate the parts of the indices of a multidimensional array.
> Thus, the expression ‘foo["A", "B"]’ really accesses foo["A\034B"]
> (see section Multidimensional Arrays).

Ex.

```
$ echo 'A,A' | gawk -F, '{col[$1,$2]++} END{for(i in col) print i}' | od -to1
0000000 101 034 101 012
0000004
```

If you want a 1d array indexed by the literal value of the string, you can use `[$1 "," $9]` or more generally `[$1 FS $9]` (the latter ensures that the solution will work for data with other separators):

```
$ echo 'A,A' | gawk -F, '{col[$1 FS $2]++} END{for(i in col) print i}'
A,A
```

If you want comma+space either use `[$1 FS" " $2]` or set `SUBSEP = FS" "` in a `BEGIN` block.

Comment: In your examples, it would make more sense to use `$0` as a single index rather than changing `SUBSEP`. To make the examples more relevant, consider reading input that is not comma-delimited.

Comment: @Kusalananda `echo 'A,A'` was just intended as a MWE (since the OP didn't provide one). IMHO using `$0` in this context would not be helpful, since the question is clearly about composing an index from separate fields.

Comment: Well, I was just looking at your second example code, and there it would be easier to use `$0` as an index to get the same effect as you get, but without having to use `FS` in the index expression.  You could also argue that the question is not about _composing an index_ but to _extract the individual parts of the index_.  It just happens that the user wants _all the parts_ with commas between them.

Answer (score 3):

When you use an index like `$1,$9` into an array in `awk`, the index that actually gets used is `$1 SUBSEP $9`, where `SUBSEP` is a character that is unlikely to occur in actual data (the actual value is implementation-defined, but octal 34, a character called "[file separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Field_separators)", is commonly used).  This is due to standard `awk` only having one-dimensional arrays.  Multi-dimensional arrays are "simulated" by concatenating the indexes with this `SUBSEP` value as delimiter.

GNU `awk` has real multi-dimensional arrays, but the syntax is `[i][j]` rather than `[i,j]`.

You may get the original bits of the index returned to you if you split the index on this `SUBSEP` value:

```c
for (i in col) {
    split(i, k, SUBSEP)
    year   = k[1]
    season = k[2]

    printf "%s, %s: %s\n", year, season, col[i]
}
```

or just

```c
for (i in col) {
    split(i, k, SUBSEP)
    printf "%s, %s: %s\n", k[1], k[2], col[i]
}
```

Both fragments above assumes that you know that your index `i` always contains *two* parts.